# What is the correct syntax for $('#form_id').serialize() and param to ajax Data

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
  $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "offreship.php",
          data: { carrier: "value", $('#form_id').serialize()}
```

Thank u for help!

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: the correct sintax to us on data: { carrier: "value", $('#form_id').serialize()}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object you provide for the `data` property is incomplete and causes the syntax error. Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "offreship.php",
    data: {
        carrier: $('#form_id').serialize()
    }
});
```

If you intend `carrier: "value"`, you need to name your property for the serialized form, like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "offreship.php",
    data: {
        carrier: "value", form: $('#form_id').serialize()
    }
});
```

Comment: You need to provide some more context. According to your snippet, it looks like you'll need to remove the quotes around value and then follow the second example in my post.